# Subfolders in visual studio code c++

Tags: c++, directory, visual-studio-code, subdirectory

So I am currently learning C++ and working through a book. The chapter I am on involves separating functions and such in different files instead of all keeping them in the main file. So for this I wanted to create a subfolder to keep all these files in, instead of having them sprawled through the main folder (Programming in C++) Here is a screenshot of the directory overview and the Chapter 4 folder is the subfolder I am trying to work out of.

[image: Picture of folder layout]

c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
 {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"

            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },

        {
            "label": "build the main grader file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "main_grader.cpp"
            ],
            "group" :{
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried numerous different ways but I can not figure out how to give the settings file the right path or whatever it needs to be able to run the simple hello world program inside the Chapter 4 folder in the main_grader.cpp file.

The error I continue to receive is:

```
g++.exe: error: main_grader.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

How could I properly link the sub folder to my main (programming in C++) folder to be able to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing the env variable "${workspaceFolder}\myFolder\*.cpp" in the args list.